# ViewFlipper is a Button?

Tags: android, button, casting, viewflipper, classcastexception

I have recently decided to add a ViewFlipper to my application, here is what I am have done:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/steve"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    // Child elements here.

</ViewFlipper>
```

**MyApp.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.steve);
```

However when I run my application I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button` for the line where I cast to a ViewFlipper.

Upon debugging, it turns out that `findViewById(R.id.steve)` returns a Button, not a ViewFlipper.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the same id for a button?

Comment: Nope. I am only using the id for the ViewFlipper. I even changed it from `view_flipper` to `steve` just to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clean and rebuild your project.  This should solve it.  And, no, ViewFlipper is not a Button or a subclass of a Button.

Comment: Thank you! I spent 2 days trying to debug this and all I needed to do was this...